# Use native WebRTC library with Windows VisualStudio/Visual C++ 2017

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, webrtc, native

I am new to WebRTC, and I started with installing the ready-to-use library package available at [Sourcey](https://sourcey.com/precompiled-webrtc-libraries/).

Using VS2017 I created a simple "hello world" console application which includes one of the webrtc native API headers.

I added the additional include path (Project config > C++ > general > add. include) and link path (Project config > Linker > add. library path).

But I got a lot of compile errors: from them I dreived that the Windows platform was not recognised, and it tried to include Unix* Headers like instead. So first fix was to add `WEBRTC_WIN`  to the preprocessor symbols.

Still I got many (1076) other errors, mostly dubious, e.g. complaining about '::' in `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` .

Second fix: I added `#define NOMINMAX` in my source file. It seems that Windows usually defines macros min() and max() which corrupt the c++ code.

So now 2 errors, complaining about `_vsnwprintf()` function maybe being not safe. As it recommended I set _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS but had to do this in the project configuration, it was not enough to set it in the source file including!

Lack of documentation on these problems with the native WebRTC libs is really annoying! Also not in the forum [Google discuss webrtc](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/discuss-webrtc). More user experiences? Tipps?

Edit: I found a nice tutorial which discourages directly using Native API and instead recommends using QT Wrapper: [Tutorial](https://de.slideshare.net/alexpiwi5/iitrtc-2017-qt-webrtc-tutorial-qt-janus-client)

Comment: It would be helpful to see the exact error messages.

Comment: @drescherjm: I added more info. I removed asking for documentation.

Comment: I found some more information: current state [link](http://webrtcbydralex.com/index.php/2018/10/14/libwebrtc-is-open-source-how-hard-can-it-be/)   Cmake installer [link](https://github.com/aisouard/libwebrtc). Cmake description [link](http://webrtcbydralex.com/index.php/2015/07/22/automating-libwebrtc-build-with-cmake/)

Comment: I found out that cosmosoftware.io offers precompiled pakages for in my opinion a small price. My company decided to save money, time and effort by doing this. Probably there are more companies like this. I have to say that I am relieved, I was starting to feel a mixture of anger and depression after days of struggle. I hope nobody sees this as advertisement, I do not get any money for it...